# Asynchronous Email Sending: Spring FrameWork

Tags: spring, email, asynchronous

We need to be able to send the email asynchronously using Spring framework.
How can we achieve it with proper exception handling and retry mechanism on email sending attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, Spring Async is good choice to initiate the business method for email sending.

However Circuit Braker isn't for you.

You really need for your purpose `RetryOperationsInterceptor` from [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)

It might looks like this:

```
<bean id="mailer" class="com.my.proj.email.EmailSender" />

<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor"/>

<bean id="asyncAdvice" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="email" expression="execution(* com.my.proj.email.EmailSender.sendEmail(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="email" advice-ref="asyncAdvice"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="email" advice-ref="retryAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```

With this config you `sendEmail` will be invoked asynchronously within provided `TaskExecutor` via `asyncAdvice`.

The `retryAdvice` takes care about the retry attempts, recovery and others retry features.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [circuit braker pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) along with Spring's [async](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception) support will help you.